# TypeError when testing static method call inside class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have a static method inside a React Component, like:

```
class DeliveryAddressScreen extends Component {
  static isAddressReady(address) {
    return !!(address)
  }

  sendAddress(address) {
    if(this.isAddressReady(address)) {
     // DO SOMETHING
    }

  }
}
```

And my test:

```
  it('sample tests', () => {
    const component = shallow(<DeliveryAddressScreen />)
    component.instance().sendAddress('Address')
    expect(true).toBe(true) // Just a sample
  })
```

the feedback is:

> **TypeError**: this.isAddressReady is not a function

Is there a right way to mock this method or something like that?

Comment: For the error, try `DeliveryAddressScreen.isAddressReady(...)` (related: [js call static method from class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614131/js-call-static-method-from-class/43614217)).

Comment: Yeah, just needed to add `this.isAddressRead = DeliveryAddressScreen.isAddressReady` to my class constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static method should be called with the class name.

```js
class DeliveryAddressScreen extends React.Component {
  static isAddressReady(address) {
    return !!(address)
  }

  sendAddress(address) {
    if(DeliveryAddressScreen.isAddressReady(address)) {
        console.log(address)
    }
  }
}

const subject = new DeliveryAddressScreen()
subject.sendAddress("test")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Static properties are properties of a class, not of an instance of a class.
```

As qouted from [Understanding static in JavaScript](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/understanding-static-in-javascript-10782149993)

Therefore you not need to call shallow. You can simply

```
import DeliveryAddressScreen from '../some/path'
it('can call class method', () => {
    expect(DeliveryAddressScreen. isAddressReady).toEqual(true)
})
```

However!!, you are trying to use `this` inside of something that has not been instantiated and therefore this will not exist

You could rewrite your static method instead to look like this without the static keyword

```
isAddressReady = (address) => {
    return true // or false
 }
```