# Enzyme shallow returns undefined for renderless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

This is my js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ProjectStore extends Component {
  static lodingCount = 0;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static setLodingCount(countValue){
    ProjectStore.lodingCount = countValue;
  }

  static getLodingCount(){
    return ProjectStore.lodingCount;
  }
}
```

I wrote a test case for the same like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import ProjectStore from '../projectStore.js';

describe('<ProjectStore />', () => {
  it('should return loading count', () => {
    const ProjectStore = shallow(<ProjectStore />);
    ProjectStore.setLodingCount(2);
    expect(ProjectStore.lodingCount).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

but when I executed `npm test` it returned:

```
ReferenceError: ProjectStore is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing a static method from a class, you don't need to render that component. All you need to do is calling that static method from that class like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

import ProjectStore from './projectStore.js';

describe('<ProjectStore />', () => {
  it('should return loading count', () => {
    ProjectStore.setLodingCount(2);
    expect(ProjectStore.lodingCount).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

You can learn more from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43614217/1727948).

Comment: Thanks @konekoya working for me. One more thing can you please suggest how can I write test case for constructor method in this case.

Comment: @rahul That's best asked in a separate question