# how to use exports object in some other js file

Tags: node.js, express

Here the user.js file with class and exports

```
class User {

        static async select() {
          const selectResult = await usersDAL.listUsers();
          return camelizeKeys(selectResult);
      }
    }

module.exports.User = User;
```

I want to use in usersApi file

```
router.get('/',(req, res) =>{

    let userList = new  User().select();
    res.send(userList);

});
```

error show

```
(intermediate value).select is not a function
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

※ At first you should use newer Node.js version 6.0 if you can.

you can export objects by `module.exports` and import by `require`.

#### how to export

```
class User {

    static async select() {
      const selectResult = await usersDAL.listUsers();
      return camelizeKeys(selectResult);
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

#### how to import

```
const User = require('../model/user') // this path is dummy.
router.get('/', async (req, res) =>{

    let userList = await User.select();
    res.send(userList);
});
```

User.select() is a method to be used as async method.
You should wrap Promise-block or use async-await statements.

Sorry my English and I don't execute the code above.
It mightn't work well.

Comment: your opinion checked but got same error => (intermediate value).select is not a function

Comment: @Md.MaidulIslam if you have how to access to the static method, you can check this link below out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614131/js-call-static-method-from-class/43614217

Answer (score 0):

By using [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) like so:

```
const User = require('./user.js').User
```

The `./user.js` path is assuming the `user.js` file is in the same directory as `usersApi`.

That being said you probably want to only export the `User`:

#### user.js

```
// ... rest of file

module.exports = User;
```

#### usersApi.js

```
const User = require('./user.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and class diagram of user.js file

```
class User {

        static async select() {
          const selectResult = await usersDAL.listUsers();
          return camelizeKeys(selectResult);
      }
    }

module.exports.User = User;
```

you want to export and use it in usersApi file. In this way, you can use

```
const User = require('.user');

router.get('/', async (req, res) =>{

    let userList = await User.User.select();
    res.send(userList);
});
```

Because you export User object in user.js file (ex: module.exports.User = User) that's way, you need User.User.select(). Another information you should know that static async method should be call inside async or promise method. For this reason I use await User.User.select()