# How can I run a snapshot test which contains a call to a static method?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In my react/jest unit test I am trying to call a static method called getSortedAppColumns(), this is part of the component:

```
static getSortedAppColumns = (appColumns, sortBy, criticalFirst) => {
...
return { id, applications: applicationsSorted, ...rest };
});
};
```

When I run this test:

```
it('should sort', () => {
    const presets = { presets: { sortCriteria: 'name' } };
    const component = (
      <AppTrackerContainer applicationStages={applicationStages} {...presets} />
    );
    const wrapper = shallow(component);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    const appList = applicationStages[0].applications;
    expect(instance.getSortedAppColumns(appList)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Of course I have this error:

> ```
> TypeError: instance.getSortedAppColumns is not a function
>
>   45 |     const instance = wrapper.instance();
>   46 |     const appList = applicationStages[0].applications;
> > 47 |     expect(instance.getSortedAppColumns(appList)).toMatchSnapshot();
> ```

Obviously a static method is not an instance but how can I utilise this static call in my jest snapshottest? Need to have a snapshot test that is the bottom line.

Comment: Hm.. Because it's not an instance method, but static one?

Comment: You can't access static members directly on the instance *in general*, this isn't anything to do with Jest (they're on the prototype). But if the static method is just a helper for the rest of what the component is doing, I wouldn't test it directly anyway; test the overall *behaviour* not your current implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AppTrackerContainer.getSortedAppColumns(appList)`

[js call static method from class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614131/js-call-static-method-from-class/43614217)

Comment: I agree you can call the static method like this but what about all the props you are passing in then?

Comment: Which props are you referring to ?

Comment: wrapper etc. see above

Comment: I don't understand. Wrapper is not  a prop, it is a [ShallowWrapper](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) created by enzyme which wraps your AppTrackerContainer component.

Comment: By the way if your main goal is just to test that static method, you truly don't need a wrapper and everything else.